# Google Sheets Blank Cells with a function

Tags: google-sheets

How do I change a simple subtraction function **=B3-A3** to return a blank cell if either of the 2 cells is blank?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B3),ISBLANK(A3)),"A3 or B3 are blank",B3-A3)
```

## Explanation

- Use ISBLANK to test if cell is blank
- Use OR to check if any of its arguments is true
- Use IF to return something if the condition returns true and other thing if the condition returns false